# Change row names in table

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to change the row names in a table without converting it to a data frame.

```
dat<-data.frame(level=rep(c("A", "B", "C", NA), each=10))
tblFun <- function(x){
  tbl <- table(x, useNA="ifany")
  res <- cbind(tbl,round(prop.table(tbl)*100,2))
  colnames(res) <- c('Count','Percentage')
  res
}
tblFun(dat[,1])
```

I want to change row 4 in the table output to "Missing". Thank you in advance!

Comment: `tbl <- tblFun(dat[,1]); rownames(tbl)[4] <- "Missing"`? Or just add the line `rownames(res)[is.na(rownames(res))] <- "Missing"` after the `colnames` assignment in your function.  It shouldn't cause problems since duplicate row names are allowed in matrices